# How do I authenticate a user's name/password trying to access Web Api hosted in Azure AD?

Tags: asp.net, api, authentication, azure, active-directory

I am trying to provide basic authentication for an ASP.net Web Api hosted in Azure. I've got to the point where I have extracted the users name/password from their http basic auth request inside of the API. I am following a tutorial that says when you get to this point do this:

```
               //You can use Websecurity or asp.net memebrship provider to login, for
                //for he sake of keeping example simple, we used out own login functionality
                if (TheRepository.LoginStudent(userName, password))
                {
                    var currentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(userName), null);
                    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = currentPrincipal;
                    return;
                }
```

Obviously he is verifying the credentials in some "repository" just for the example. What do I do here to verify the credentials for a user I have added in Azure AD? (Just for a quick, yes you are a user, you are authenticated, move on...) When I look at the Authorization endpoints in my application page inside of azure AD, i see the following options:

- FEDERATION METADATA DOCUMENT
- WS-FEDERATION SIGN-ON ENDPOINT
- SAML-P SIGN-ON ENDPOINT
- SAML-P SIGN-OUT ENDPOINT
- WINDOWS AZURE AD GRAPH API ENDPOINT
- OAUTH 2.0 TOKEN ENDPOINT
- OAUTH 2.0 AUTHORIZATION ENDPOINT

I tried OAuth2.0 with the auth code flow before trying this basic auth, but couldnt get it to work (possibly overkill?) because we want to be able to give users a token and allow them to immediately begin making calls without having to redirect to a browser, etc. Our users will mostly be using desktop applications...

Comment: I assume you have some client application which is collecting the username/password and making the call to the API.  Typically this client app would make the call to Azure AD to get the auth token and then include the auth token in the API call.

Comment: @BenV, can you go into more detail about what "make the call to Azure AD" means? That is where I am confused. There are all of these different auth endpoints and flows like Oauth and SAML-P, but how do I just do the equivalent of something like ... try(azure.login(username, password)) ? I just want basic authentication, that is it

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn499820.aspx#BKMK_Web) is the flow I was describing.  It's not possible to send a username/pwd over the wire to Azure AD like what you're wanting.  You can use the Graph API to query a if a username exists, but you have to use one of the standard protocols to authenticate.

Comment: @BenV I would like to use a flow like this (OAuth2.0), but there are two issues: 1) My company's app is a desktop application (written in non .net language). So I don't know how I would capture the auth code in the redirect URI. 2) What if we want to give access to developers not using our app. They have to code up a browser that captures the auth code in the redirect uri? Maybe I'm overthinking this or missing a step?

Comment: 1) See Vittorio's answer below. 2) How do users authenticate to your desktop app or these other developers' apps?

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD comes with a number of client libraries that make it easy to get a token and use it in web API calls. If the dev stack you are targeting is covered (e.g .NET desktop, android, iOS, windows store, winphone...), you are in a great spot: just download a sample that approximate your scenario (native client) from https://github.com/AzureADSamples/, and you'll be on your way.
If the technology you are using is NOT covered, things are a bit more complicated. One thing you can do is examining the source of any of the existing libraries (they are all OSS and available on github at https://github.com/AzureAD/) and reproduce it in your language/stack of choice.
Hope this helps!
V.